# Change JavaScript in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to translate this code into actual TypeScript. Could you help me there?

```
import mongoose, { Promise } from 'mongoose';
Promise = global.Promise;

const db = {};

db.mongoose = mongoose;

db.user = require("./user.model");
db.role = require("./role.model");

db.ROLES = ["user", "admin", "moderator"];

export default db;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you'd provide us with what you have tried and achieved so that it is easier to modify your code.

A  way to do this would be to type this in a TypeScript file in an editor that provides linting for TypeScript like Visual Studio Code. Then check all the errors and fix them.